# Django. Moving a redis query outside of a view. Making the query results available to all views

Tags: django, pandas, redis, celery

My Django app has read-only "dashboard" views of data in a Pandas DataFrame. The DataFrame is built from a redis database query.

Code snippet below:

```
# Part 1. Get values from the redis database and load them into a DataFrame.
r = redis.StrictRedis(**redisconfig)
keys = r.keys(pattern="*")
keys.sort()
    values = r.mget(keys)
    values = [x for x in vals if x != None]
redisDataFrame = pd.DataFrame(map(json.loads, vals))

# Part 2. Manipulate the DataFrame for display
myViewData = redisDataFrame
#Manipulation of myViewData
#Exact steps vary based from one view to the next.
fig = myViewData.plot()
```

The code for part 1 (query redis) is inside every single view that displays that data. And the views have an update interval of 1 second. If I have 20 users viewing dashboards, the redis database is getting queried 20 times a second.

Because the query sometimes takes several seconds, Django spawns multiple threads, many of which hang and slow down the whole system.

I want to put part 1 (querying the redis database) into its own codeblock. Django will query redis (and make the redisDataFrame object) once per second. Each view will copy redisDataFrame into its own object, but it won't query the redis database over and over again. I think this will help performance.

I see some options for this, but I'm not sure what's the best option. Can you point me in the right direction?

-Custom context processor. I could put the 'Part 1' code into a custom context processor, using sched to execute once per second.

```
import time, sched
schedule = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
r = redis.StrictRedis(**redisconfig)
def query_redis:
    keys = r.keys(pattern="*")
    keys.sort()
        values = r.mget(keys)
        values = [x for x in vals if x != None]
    retuen redisDataFrame = pd.DataFrame(map(json.loads, vals))
scheduler.enter(1, 1, redis_data_frame = query_redis())
return redisDataFrame
```

```
from mysite.context_processors import redisDataFrame
...
myViewData = redisDataFrame
```

-Celery. I'm not familiar with this, but it's often recommended. That said, Celery uses redis as a "broker" between Python apps. If Celery writes to a redis database, that doesn't help my issue of improving access to redis.

I feel like this issue (multiple users accessing read-only DataFrames) is a common task that's easily solved. I just don't know how to solve it. Can you help?

Comment: Celery is a task queue. It allows you to asynchronously throw tasks into a queue to be consumed by workers later and have the current thread continue it's work. You can set how many workers consume tasks from your queue, so you can limit how many tasks are writing data at any time. Redis is a cache that can be used as a DB. Queries should not be taking several seconds to complete. You should focus on optimizing the query, but most likely you'll have to use an actual SQL DB engine (PostgreSQL, MySQL) with proper indexes set up.

Comment: Also, if you have a chunk of code that's run by every view, you should probably write custom middleware. It's not as scary as it sounds; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/middleware/

Comment: Thanks. I will incorporate custom middlewares into my project. However, that doesn't help this particular issue. I'm trying to prevent a chunk of code from being run by every view. I want the redis query to run in its own thread and update a variable that's accessible to all views.

Comment: Celery would be perfect for this. You build tasks and they run in their own thread. Celery Beat allows you to schedule these tasks, so it can run once per second.